# Strange bug between empty objet and empty object property in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So I just stumble across a strange 'bug' in Laravel I'd like to have explanation about.

So basicaly if I do

```
@if(!empty($p -> $myObject)) ...SHOW STUFF... @endif
```

This is displaying nothing as if the object was empty... BUT

If I `var_dump($p -> $myObject)` I got a populated object. AND

If I use a specific champ like :

```
@if(!empty($p -> $myObject -> name)) ...SHOW STUFF... @endif
```

It is displaying the name of the object.

So what is going on there ? Can someone explain me the process ?

Comment: php `empty` doesn't work on objects.

Comment: Use isset instead empty @if(!isset($p -> $myObject)) ...SHOW STUFF... @endif

Answer (score 3):

For laravel object can be check with `isEmpty` method:

```
collect([])->isEmpty();
```

More:

https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-isempty
https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_isEmpty